# View count restriction isn't working for /search/advanced.

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, api-v2.1

I have constructed the following URL, but the questions returned don't contain anywhere near 50k views, despite the query string parameter:

http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/search/advanced?site=askubuntu&views=50000

Instead I get questions that look like this:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      ...
      "view_count": 600
      ...
    }
}
```

According to [the documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search):

> "views - the minimum number of views returned questions must have"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a caching bug actually, a few parameters weren't being considered when doing a cache lookup (such as views) so you'd get back non-sense data.

It's been fixed in the latest deploy.